# HttpRequestException: An error occurred when retrieving Google user information (Forbidden). In Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to enable social login in my asp.net core application. i have successfully integrated facebook and twitter and it works fine. But while integrating Google, on returning to the callback URL it spits out this error page.

I am also using a custom controller for the process

```
[Route("signin/{provider}")]
public IActionResult SignIn(string provider, string returnUrl = null) => 
        Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? 
          "/" }, provider);
```

The above code is my custom controller call auth.cs.

[image: error page]

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultSignInScheme = 
CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddFacebook(options => 
          {
            options.AppId = "";
            options.AppSecret = "";
        })
.AddTwitter(options =>
        {
            options.ConsumerKey = "";
            options.ConsumerSecret = 
"";
})
.AddGoogle(options => {
            options.ClientId = 
"<my client Id>";
            options.ClientSecret = "<my client secret>";
})
.AddCookie(options => {
            options.LoginPath = "/auth/signin";
});
```

I expected once I sign in using googles Oauth 2.* it should redirect back to my application instead of displaying the error page

Comment: Where is your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this error because i didn't Enable the Services from  [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/)

so when i did enable it, everything works fine.

this was the error i encountered before enabling it. [image: My error page]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.AddGoogle("Google", o=>
{
    o.ClientId = "<insert here>";
    o.ClientSecret = "<insert here>";
    o.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
    o.ClaimActions.Clear();
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Same issue, I was stuck approximately for two days. Fortunately i went deep down and found something new that in asp.net core 2* and above version, you need to mention `UserInformationEndpoint`. It will be available in downloaded json file from console.google.developer.
Please find below details.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "196275387351-has575ff9m45ka8ld17s0qtps42jkmtt.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            options.ClientSecret = "MoYpnVChG8VeDiGCw4XYrLH0";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint= "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs";
          });
```

Controller : Account

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}
```

Downloaded Json

```
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> Blockquote
>   In January 2019 Google started to shut down Google+ sign in and developers must move to a new Google sign in system by March. The ASP.NET Core 2.1 and 2.2 packages for Google Authentication will be updated in February to accommodate the changes. For more information and temporary mitigations for ASP.NET Core, see this GitHub issue. This tutorial has been updated with the new setup process.

Comment: You are the real MVP

Answer (score 0):

Per the official [Quick Start](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html), have you tried with `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;`

```
    .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        options.ClientId = "<insert here>";
        options.ClientSecret = "<insert here>";
    })
```

Comment: in which dll file does "IdentityServerConstants" exist?